# Slow query plan with small LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, postgresql-performance

A query generated by our web framework leads to different query plans, depending on the number of rows to be returned. The problem lies within the combination of a low `LIMIT` and the `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM "herald_notification"
 INNER JOIN "herald_activity"
    ON ("herald_notification"."activity_id" = "herald_activity"."id")
 INNER JOIN "herald_user"
    ON ("herald_notification"."user_id" = "herald_user"."id")
 INNER JOIN "herald_user" T4
    ON ("herald_activity"."actor_id" = T4."id")
 WHERE ("herald_activity"."active" = true AND "herald_notification"."user_id" = 8008)
 ORDER BY "herald_activity"."timestamp" DESC
 LIMIT n;
```

If `LIMIT` is `1` or `2`, a different query plan will be executed compared to `LIMIT 3` and higher. The first query plan takes 1.5 seconds to execute, while the other only takes 40 ms.

```sql
--- LIMIT 1 or LIMIT 2
Limit  (cost=1001.46..2827.53 rows=2 width=292) (actual time=1541.829..1546.167 rows=2 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                               
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1001.46..242042.66 rows=264 width=292) (actual time=1541.827..1541.912 rows=2 loops=1)                                                                                                                                               
         ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.17..242031.05 rows=264 width=189) (actual time=1541.734..1546.063 rows=2 loops=1)                                                                                                                                        
               Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
               Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.14..241000.56 rows=110 width=189) (actual time=1023.456..1023.483 rows=1 loops=3)                                                                                                                                      
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..240966.38 rows=110 width=86) (actual time=1023.449..1023.474 rows=1 loops=3)                                                                                                                                 
                           ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using herald_activity_timestamp_574bae7d on herald_activity  (cost=0.42..44554.07 rows=385804 width=72) (actual time=0.036..195.016 rows=308678 loops=3)                                           
                                 Filter: active                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 14746                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                           ->  Index Scan using unique_user_and_activity on herald_notification  (cost=0.43..0.51 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=926033)                                                                              
                                 Index Cond: ((activity_id = herald_activity.id) AND (user_id = 8008))                                                                                                                                                         
                     ->  Index Scan using herald_user_pkey on herald_user t4  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=2)                                                                                                     
                           Index Cond: (id = herald_activity.actor_id)                                                                                                                                                                                         
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=0.041..0.042 rows=1 loops=2)                                                                                                                                                         
               ->  Index Scan using herald_user_pkey on herald_user  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=0.047..0.048 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                              
                     Index Cond: (id = 8008)                   
 Planning Time: 2.943 ms                                       
 Execution Time: 1546.441 ms
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/Usyx

```sql
--- LIMIT >=3
Limit  (cost=3337.09..3337.09 rows=3 width=292) (actual time=0.201..0.204 rows=3 loops=1)                                     
   ->  Sort  (cost=3337.09..3337.75 rows=264 width=292) (actual time=0.200..0.200 rows=3 loops=1)                              
         Sort Key: herald_activity."timestamp" DESC            
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB                  
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7.58..3333.67 rows=264 width=292) (actual time=0.125..0.147 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                    
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7.29..3251.65 rows=264 width=189) (actual time=0.090..0.103 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                                                                                              
                     ->  Index Scan using herald_user_pkey on herald_user  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                        
                           Index Cond: (id = 8008)             
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=7.00..3240.71 rows=264 width=86) (actual time=0.059..0.070 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                                                                                         
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on herald_notification  (cost=6.57..966.13 rows=277 width=14) (actual time=0.031..0.032 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                                                        
                                 Recheck Cond: (user_id = 8008)                                                                
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=1                                                                          
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on herald_notification_user_id_dccf7862  (cost=0.00..6.51 rows=277 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                                   
                                       Index Cond: (user_id = 8008)                                                            
                           ->  Index Scan using herald_activity_pkey on herald_activity  (cost=0.42..8.21 rows=1 width=72) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=3)                                                                                           
                                 Index Cond: (id = herald_notification.activity_id)                                            
                                 Filter: active                
               ->  Index Scan using herald_user_pkey on herald_user t4  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=3)                                                                                                           
                     Index Cond: (id = herald_activity.actor_id)                                                               
 Planning Time: 2.819 ms                                       
 Execution Time: 0.414 ms
```

https://explain.depesz.com/s/8lXP

The are 1.7m rows in the table `notification`, 900k in `activity` and 35k in `user`. I can reproduce this both on PostgreSQL 10 and 12.1.

What did help was to set `default_statistics_target` to a sample size of 7500.

What I'm wondering now is whether this is actually a good approach or if there are more suitable options to achieve the same outcome. I'm hesitant because from 100 to 7500 is a very huge jump.

Does something strike you as very wrong in this scenario?

Comment: Thank you for referencing the answer. I already increased `default_statistics_target` and it does indeed help. As the value needed to help with my issue (i.e. `~7500`) deviates dramatically from the default `100` and I am by no means a database expert, I want to make sure that I'm heading in the right direction or if there are other means to make PostgreSQL use another plan. 

Regarding your second suggestion in that other post: as stated in the beginning, the query is generated by a framework so I modifying the query is a bit more complicated than if I wrote it myself.

Comment: @laurenz-albe You previously commented on this question, asking me whether your answer in the question linked as a duplicate solved my problem and I stated in the above comment that I already applied the steps and want to know whether this is the right approach. I find it a bit rude to see that you deleted your comment and went ahead to declare my question as a duplicate without any further comments about it. Would you please care to elaborate on your decision? Thanks.